# Passing json data from an api to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json, api

Am a newbie in json/javascript so please bear with me. Am getting json data from an api url that loads sth like

```
 {
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
```

i need it as a javascript variable on a script file

```
var employess={
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

Ave tried

```
$.getJSON(myUrl",function(data){ $("#selector").data("JSONP",data); alert(data); });
```

Comment: JSON is a string format, not a Javascript object. `var object = JSON.parse(jsonString)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: What problem are you having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your JSON string a variable `var jsonString`

then...

```
var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```