# JavaScript load JSON data from an API url

Tags: javascript, json, api, url, var

I'm working on a javascript program that needs to get data from an API.

My problem is I'm not able to go from the url string to the actual JSON data.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494490/passing-json-data-from-an-api-to-a-javascript-variable) and they provide this answer :

**Put your JSON string a variable var jsonString**

**then...**

**var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);**

So I ended up with :

```
var url = "https://pixabay.com/api/?";

var data = JSON.parse(url);
```

But this is not working. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't see what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Comment: At the moment you're just trying to JSON parse a URL string, you need to make a call to retrieve the content at that URL, then parse the content.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Thanks a lot DBS, how do I make a call to retrieve the content ? That's where I'm stuck :/

Comment: Alon Eltan I've looked into this documentation but I must admit this is a lot of complex information to me, most of the syntax in this page is new to me ( I don't know anything about ajax or jQuery ). Can someone try and explain to me with maybe a more specific answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass variables and their values in the url.

```
var url = "https://pixabay.com/api/?var1= " + var1;
var var1 = req.params.var1;
var jsonString = { "var1": var1 }
var data = JSON.parse(url);
```

You need the string that is in JSON format before you can parse it.

Comment: I don't understand. The url is completed with fixed values ( search parameters like API key, key words, image type and so on ). What I need is somehow to get the script to fetch the data at that url.